# How purchase payment method is disable for front end if admin enabled the setting

Tags: php, magento

I have a purchase Payment method module on my website and i want that purchase payment method is only visible in Admin but not on front end on Payment Step.i create a configuration setting for admin if admin enable this setting after that only purchase payment method is shows on admin side.

my model file

```
<?php
class Magentomod_Purchaseorder_Model_Method_Purchaseorder extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

protected $_canUseInternal              = true; 
protected $_canUseCheckout              = false; 
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = false;

protected $_code  = 'purchaseorder';
protected $_formBlockType = 'payment/form_purchaseorder';
protected $_infoBlockType = 'payment/info_purchaseorder';

public function isAvailable($quote = null) {

}
public function assignData($data)
{
    if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
        $data = new Varien_Object($data);
    }

    $this->getInfoInstance()->setPoNumber($data->getPoNumber());
    return $this;
}
```

}

i just want if value of $isActive = Mage::getStoreConfig('purchaseorder/purchaseorder_config/enabled'); is 1 then

```
protected $_canUseInternal              = true; 
protected $_canUseCheckout              = false; 
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = false;
```

else

```
protected $_canUseInternal              = true; 
protected $_canUseCheckout              = true; 
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = true;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Confused slightly by your explination, but guessing you need:

```
protected $_canUseInternal              = true; 
protected $_canUseCheckout              = false; 
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = false;

public function __construct()
{
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('purchaseorder/purchaseorder_config/enabled') === 1) {

        $this->_canUseCheckout              = true; 
        $this->_canUseForMultishipping      = true;

    }
}
```